# Output in a textbox in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, output

I'm trying to input 2 parameters and output it an another TEXTBOX.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="proj4js/lib/proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
function func1 (x,y){

     var z=x+y
     document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;

    }                           

</script>
<form >
first input:<br>
<input id="Y" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="X" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br> 
The Answer:<br>
<input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 

<br><br>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="func1(parseInt(document.getElementById('X').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('Y').value))">Try it</button>
```

What is wrong here? I tried this to show the result as simple paragraph and I succeed, but I need to display it in a textbox.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("Z").value = z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:-

`document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;`

with

`document.getElementById("Z").value = z;`

Answer (score 1):

An `<input>` element uses `value` and not `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("Z").value = z;
```